# How to configure Maven External Repositories to be Dependency Specific

Tags: java, maven

In my Maven configuration I have 6 repositories. 3 Open Source for Geo Tools Java framework and 3 proprietary with encrypted credential access.

```
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net repository</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>osgeo</id>
        <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
        <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>boundless</id>
      <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
    </repository>
```

I added the external repositories mentioned here: http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/eclipse.html

I added the plugin repositories as well and updated my `settings.xml` so the repositories in both matched.

```
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net repository</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>osgeo</id>
        <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
        <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>boundless</id>
      <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
    </pluginRepository>
```

I even downloaded the `jar`s I need for these Geo Tool dependencies and placed them in my `.m2` folder.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
      <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
      <version>18.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
      <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
      <version>18.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

However, when I try and run a `mvn clean install -X` I can see that I am getting a `401 Unauthorized` when Maven is trying to transfer `org.geotools` `jar`s to/from the proprietary repositories I have configured, but I don't even want Maven to try.

How can I configure Maven so that for `org.geotools.*` load from these 3 repositories : `<id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>`, `<id>osgeo</id>`,  `<id>boundless</id>` and otherwise load from the proprietary repositories?

I heard that I can configure a proxy, but nobody is explaining how I would do that. I tried to store the jars I need for Geo Tools in my proprietary repository, but was told I can't. I also tried to configure a mirror to direct traffic to those external repositories only in my `settings.xml` like this below, but am seeing issues of cannot transfer `jar`s from/to that only exist in the proprietary repository.

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>boundless</id>
        <name>Boundless Repository Mirror</name>
        <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

Comment: Do that in your repository manager....Nexus, Artifactory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this can be done with maven but can be done with Artifactory virtual repositories. Other repository management tools should have similar concepts. 
Basically you setup a Artifactory repository and your applications should refer to this repository. And you can configure inside Artifactory to which jars should be download from which repositories.

> Consider that the Include Patterns and Exclude Patterns for a repository are as follows:
>   Include Patterns: org/apache/**,com/acme/**
>   Exclude Patterns: com/acme/exp-project/**
>   In this case, Artifactory will search the repository for org/apache/maven/parent/1/1.pom and com/acme/project-x/core/1.0/nit-1.0.jar but not for com/acme/exp-project/core/1.1/san-1.1.jar because com/acme/exp-project/** is specified as an Exclude pattern.

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Common+Settings#CommonSettings-Package

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories

Comment: I am using JFrog already and will try and configure this pattern in that repository, but it's a shared repo for over 100 applications. I need to ensure it won't impact those other applications for my 1 use-case.

Comment: @jDub9 In Artifactory you can define more than one repositories.
If you dont want to affect any other applications create a new repo for your project (like `my-project-repo`). 
The configuration that are mentioned in the answer are applied to repository level. So only applications that refer to `my-project-repo` will be affected.